# How to set values in a dataframe based on rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id  value  
111  0.222 
222  2.253
333  0.444
444  21.256
....
```

I want to add a new column `flag` and the first half of the rows, set `flag` to 0, the rest is set to `1`:

```
id         value    flag 
111        0.222    0 
222        2.253    0
333        0.444    0
444       21.256    0
...
8888     1212.500   1
9999     0.025      1
```

What's the best way to do this? I tired the following:

```
df['flag'][:int(len(df) / 2)] = 0
df['flag'][int(len(df) / 2):] = 1
```

But this gave me `KeyError: 'flag'`, assuming probably I need to create an empty column with name `flag`? Can someone help please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you create an empty column, you would get some warning/error due to chain indexing. Try assign at once:

```
df['flag'] = (np.arange(len(df)) >= (len(df)//2)).astype(int)
```

Or

```
l = len(df)//2
df['flag'] = [0] * s + [1] * (len(df) - l)
```